# Names for the degrees for symptoms from drought (or other damage) done to trees

Tags: botany, ecology, plant-anatomy, trees

Looking out my window, I see trees suffering from drought. I once knew the name for the degrees visible, but I have forgotten and can't find it on the net.

**Attempt at describing "level of dryness"**

- Level 1

  The tree is completely without leaves (at a season where it should have at least some leaves).
- Level 2

  The tree has at least some bushels of leaves on the main branches, interspersed with dry areas without any leaves.
- Level 3

  The tree has leaves all around the main branches (those which are attached to the stem), but not on any secondary branches.
- Level 4

  The tree has leaves on the main branches and secondary branches.

**Explicit question**

What are the names for those levels, or other levels, in case I missed some?